# Deserialize list of lists in C#

Tags: c#, json, deserialization, json-deserialization

I have the following response from an API

`[[{\"message\":\"example message\"}]]`

I tried to deserialize it as a list of lists as follow

```
public class ErrorMessage
{
    [JsonProperty("message")]
    public string Message;
}
public class ErrorMessages
{
    public List<ErrorMessage> Messages;
}
public class ErrorMessagesList
{
    public List<ErrorMessages> MessagesList;
}
```

The deserialization fails, how can I deserialize it?

Comment: Try changing the property type to a list of lists?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This code works for me:

```
 var someJson = "[[{\"message\":\"example message\"}]]";
 var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<List<ErrorMessage>>>(someJson);
 Debug.Assert(result.First().First().Message == "example message");
```

You have a collection of a collection of instances of your `ErrorMessage` class.  In the code, I deserialize into a List of a List of ErrorMessage.  So the first item in result is a List of ErrorMessage.  The first item in that list is an ErrorMessage, and the `Message` property of that object is `"example message"`.

If your JSON looked like this, it would still deserialize with that `DeserializeObject` call, but it would be more obvious what you were looking at:

```
var moreJson = @"[
                    [
                        {""message"": ""First message""},
                        {""message"": ""Second message""},
                        {""message"": ""Third message""}
                    ],
                    [
                        {""message"": ""Fourth message""},
                        {""message"": ""Fifth message""}
                    ]
                ]";
```

The List of list of ErrorMessage is more obvious in this code.  But, it's the same type in both examples

Answer (score 0):

What deserializer are you using?  You are missing the Messages or Messages List property in your JSON.

```
{"Messages":[[{"message":"example message"}]]}
```

Would be able to be deseralized as:

```
public class ErrorMessage
{
    [JsonProperty("message")]
    public string Message;
}

public class ErrorMessages
{
    public List<List<ErrorMessage>> Messages;
}
```

Comment: Your json (first code block) has mixed escaped and non-escaped quotes.